# How to show list menu when I bring a mouse cursor on a wxPython listbox

Tags: python, wxpython

I made a wxPython listbox containing available serial com ports.

My example is this.

```
import wx

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent = None, title= "ListBox Test", size = (300,200))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.listBox1 = wx.ListBox(self.panel, -1, name='listBox1', pos =(50, 20), size= (100, 20), choices = ["Com 1", "Com 2", "Com 3", "Com 4"])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

I want to show a whole com port list to select a com port when I bring my mouse cursor on the listbox.

Could anyone show me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest a `ComboBox` or a `Choice`

```
import wx

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent = None, title= "ListBox Test", size = (600,200))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.listBox1 = wx.ComboBox(self.panel, -1, pos =(50, 20), size= (100, 30), choices = ["Com 1", "Com 2", "Com 3", "Com 4"])
        self.listBox1.SetSelection(0)

        self.choice1 = wx.Choice(self.panel, -1, pos =(250, 20), size= (100, 30), choices = ["Com 1", "Com 2", "Com 3", "Com 4"])
        self.choice1.SetSelection(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]